# avoid opening the browser while running selenium webDriver test cases

Tags: java, selenium

i have been getting a lot of help from you guys and i am really glad.  have passed these huddles,

[web page source downloaded through Jsoup is not equal to the actual web page source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19961896/web-page-source-downloaded-through-jsoup-is-not-equal-to-the-actual-web-page-sou)

[How to download a Web page source using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19964677/how-to-download-a-web-page-source-using-selenium)

and now i am finally here for the last huddle (hopefully)

while running the selenium test case, like this,

```
 WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        FluentWebDriver fwd = new FluentWebDriver(driver);

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5L, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("http://www.justdial.com/Bangalore/Tape-Dealers-%3Cnear%3E-Bangalore-City-Railway-Station/ct-12976/page-5");

       String res = driver.getPageSource();
```

it opens up the web browser and starts downloading all the images that are there in the page and caues a delay for the source code to be downloaded from my java program. how can i avoid opening up my browser in this scenario?? i just want the page source and NO graphical content. and hence avoid the delay too... please help!! thanks in advance!!

Comment: You want a Headless driver.  You can either use HTMLUnit driver, or PhantomDriver.

Answer (score 1):

I haven´t used FluentWebDriver but I guess you could try replacing the FirefoxDriver with the HtmlUnitDriver:

Replace:

`WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();`

With:

`HtmlUnitDriver driver = new HtmlUnitDriver();`